# Moving table join from inside query to outside makes it go from running in 7 seconds, to 3 minutes. (Image Varbinary issues)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that when simplified looks like this.

```
SELECT
    s.Company_Code
    ,s.Division_Code
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
    ,sum(id.Quantity) qty
    --,(sp.Image_Thumbnail) Item_Image  
FROM 
    invoices_detail id
    join style s on id.Item_Number = s.Item_Number and id.Color_Code = s.Color_Code
    join Style_Size ss on s.Item_Number = ss.Item_Number and s.Color_Code = ss.Color_Code
    left join Style_Pictures sp on s.Item_Number = sp.Item_Number and s.Color_Code = sp.Color_Code     
group by
    s.Company_Code
    ,s.Division_Code
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
```

This works well, unless I want to add the item image, and comment out the

```
--,(sp.Image_Thumbnail) Item_Image
```

line.

Our image field is of the data type Image and even though I know it's deprecated, that is how the database is set up and I can't change it.

So adding it to the group by returns this error

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

So Googling around on the internet, a solution seems to be to cast the column to `VARBINARY`, in both the select and group by fields.

That works, except the problem is, once I make this CAST, it causes SSRS to show a red X instead of actually showing the image. Without the cast, the image shows the image correctly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3ISP.png

So the next step I tried is to put the image table outside of the main query, to not have it be included in the group by.

That query looks like this.

```
Select 
st.*
,(sp.Image_Thumbnail) Item_Image
from (

SELECT 
    s.Company_Code
    ,s.Division_Code
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
    ,sum(id.Quantity) qty

FROM 
    invoices_detail id
    join style s on id.Item_Number=s.Item_Number and id.Color_Code=s.Color_Code
    join Style_Size ss on s.Item_Number=ss.Item_Number and s.Color_Code=ss.Color_Code

group by
    s.Company_Code
    ,s.Division_Code
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
) st
left join Style_Pictures sp on st.Item_Number=sp.Item_Number and st.Color_Code=sp.Color_Code
```

Now the query goes from taking a few seconds to run, to multiple minutes.
And the rows roll in very slowly, instead of all at once.

Can anyone help me find a solution to this issue?

Either a way to make the SSRS report not show the Red X when its cast as a `Varbinary`, or figure out why moving the table outside makes the query run so long, and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Attaching what I tried to do with the CAST

```
SELECT 
    s.Company_Code
    ,s.Division_Code
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
    ,sum(id.Quantity) qty
    ,CAST(sp.Image_Thumbnail as Varbinary) Item_Image

FROM 
    invoices_detail id
    join style s on id.Item_Number=s.Item_Number and id.Color_Code=s.Color_Code
    join Style_Size ss on s.Item_Number=ss.Item_Number and s.Color_Code=ss.Color_Code
    left join Style_Pictures sp on s.Item_Number=sp.Item_Number and s.Color_Code=sp.Color_Code 

group by
    s.Company_Code
    ,s.Division_Code
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
    ,CAST(sp.Image_Thumbnail as Varbinary)
```

Comment: Show us what you tried when you used `CAST`

Comment: But your query needs a re-structure, instead of building a large query and grouping on loads of columns, build the minimum query to get the grouped data, then join the other data on.

Comment: Hey @DaleK I added how I implemented the CAST at the bottom of my post, but it's just a super simple basic CAST to Varbinary. And to be honest, my real query doesn't look much different from the query in the question. And also, that exact query in question has the same slowdown issue as the full large query.

Comment: This `CAST(sp.Image_Thumbnail as Varbinary)` is the problem - you **MUST** specify a size for all `VAR..` datatypes. You need `CAST(sp.Image_Thumbnail as Varbinary(max))`

Comment: I actually tried it with (Max), as one of the many thing I tried to fix it. It didn't work, everything ran the same as before.

Comment: I find that very hard to believe, because `varbinary(max)` is functionally equivalent to `image`.

Comment: You're right, the problem wasn't that it didn't work, is that it made the query run in 4 minutes again, just like the outside join. But the inside join only takes a few seconds. It's just the fact that I cant group by max(image)

Answer (score 1):

Casting to a `varbinary` without specifying a length uses the default length of 30 bytes:

```sql
print datalength(cast(replicate('a', 1000) as varbinary)); -- prints 30, not 1000
```

Presumably your thumbnail images are each much larger than 30 bytes.

So when you cast to `varbinary` without specifying a length the results come back quickly because you aren't returning much data, just 30 bytes for each image.

When you move the join to the image outside the `group by` subquery and without the cast to `varbinary`, you are returning the full image data.

It takes a lot longer to transfer a large amount of data back to the client than it takes to transfer a small amount of data back to the client.

If a lot of `Styles` share the same `Style_Picture`, then your existing query structure will return the same image multiple times, that's just how `join` works.

Instead, this is one of those rare cases where it may be better to return two separate result sets. One result set for the normal data, and a separate result set for the distinct `Style_Pictures` needed by that data. You then "join" them back together for presentation in the front end.

But if each `Style` has a distinct `Style_Picture`, this approach won't make any difference. If you are returning a lot of rows at once, you might want to look into reducing the amount of data returned in a single report execution by forcing the user to enter more filter values, and/or only returning a limited number of rows.

Comment: How can I join it on the front end? I use SSRS. I tried creating a separate table that was just Item_number, and picture, but that kept the same results. since all the item information is in the Style table anywayws, and we just add the Style Picture table.

Comment: @user7959439 It's been years since I built an SSRS report, but google found this https://sqlskull.com/2021/04/23/join-two-datasets-in-ssrs/ But as I said in my comment, if every style has its own unique style picture then you won't see a performance improvement with the two-result solution, because it would be sending just as many pictures across the network to be rendered as it would in the one-result solution. You will only see a benefit with the two-result solution if the count of distinct pictures is much lower than the count of distinct styles.